# verification of solution: Homology of RP2 with ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I need help verifying what I am doing wrong.

I think of $\Bbb{R}P^2$ as the upper hemisphere of $S^2$ and then choose an open set A around the north pole, an open set $B = \{\text{upper hemisphere}\} - \{\text{a closed disk}\}$ around the north pole. Then $H(A)$ is isomorphic to $H(\{*\})$, $H(B)$ is isomorphic to $H(S^1)$ and $H(A\cap B) \cong H(S^1)$. I am having some problem calculating $H_2(\Bbb{R}P^2)$. I have the following exact sequence:

$H_2(A) \oplus H_2(B) \xrightarrow{f} H_{2}(X) \xrightarrow{g} H_1(A \cap B) \xrightarrow{i_*,j_*} H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B) $

This is the same as:
$$ 0 \xrightarrow{f} H_{2}(X) \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{Z}_2 \xrightarrow{i_*,j_*}  \mathbb{Z}_2 $$

$\operatorname{im}(f) = \ker(g) = 0$, so $H_2(X) \cong \operatorname{im}(g) = \ker(i_*,j_*)$. Now $i_*$ is inclusion into $0$, and $j_*$  is injective, so $\ker(i_*,j_*)= 0$, so $H_2(X)= 0$.

I know that this $H_2(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ if the ring is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The problem is that $j_*$ is a multiplication by $2$ and hence a trivial map that collapses everything to $0$, so $g$ should be an isomorphism. The reason for that is because antipodes of $\partial D^2\approx S^1$  is identified, which means it wrapps twice around the cycle of $A\cap B$.

Comment: can you clarify? what do you mean by wrapping twice around the cycle $A \bigcap B$?

Comment: You may want to draw a picture, and observe the map induced by the inclusion, $j_*:H_1(A\cap B)\to H_1(B)$. Think of it as an analogue to Van-Kampen's Thm.